# Safety concern building a fire pit out of reclaimed bricks

Tags: brick, masonry, fire-pit

I have a bunch of reclaimed (broken) bricks left over from building a patio. The bricks are from an old home that was knocked over and buried for some time. I would like to use these to build a fire pit on the patio, but I've read there can be some safety concerns using bricks/blocks that aren't "fire  safe".

My question is, how concerned should I be about using these old bricks? It seems unlikely that they'd blow up to me but I like to keep things as safe as possible.

Are there are any other things I should be concerned about such as mortar type? Base? etc?

Here are the bricks (red ones):

[image: fire pit bricks]

Comment: Close proximity to fire really requires the use of fire bricks and high heat mortar. I’ve heard of regular bricks right next to a fire exploding, but I’ve never seen it in person

Comment: Agreed, random brick are not for fires.

Comment: suggestion for future questions: if you have a question about a brick, do not post a picture of a pile of bricks, such as the one you posted, because the picture is useless ... post a closeup of one brick ... that way we can see any markings on the brick .... this suggestion applies to any item that you may be asking about

Comment: @jsotola fair enough. Was at work and didn't happen to have a close up of the bricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the basic structure with these bricks, then line the fire pit itself with fire bricks. That's how fireplaces are made.